# How to detect chroot on illumos/solaris?

Tags: solaris, chroot

How can a running C-program detect if it is running in "chroot" on illumos/solaris?

There is a Debian utility [1] which uses some tricks on linux, freebsd, hurd.

How to do it on illumos/solaris?

[1] http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=users/clint/debianutils.git;a=blob;f=ischroot.c;h=bed67f9f655d26906e3d65fd290698dce5402a89;hb=HEAD

Comment: The fact that it's detectable on other platforms seems buglike.  It's probably not supposed to be detectable at all programmatically without superuser privileges.

Answer (score 2):

There's [this thread on *comp.unix.solaris*](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2010-04/msg00180.html) which details various methods to find out whether Solaris runs inside a zone (container / chroot-on-lots-of-steroids) or a VM. Particularly extensive is [the list in this posting](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2010-04/msg00185.html) (seems to have come from [this blog post](http://alittlestupid.com/2009/03/30/how-to-identify-a-solaris-non-global-zone/). I'll recreate some of the items relating to zones here - those that are available to non-root users.

- The [`/usr/bin/zonename`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/zonename-1.html) command tells you something different than "global"
- The Solaris kernel "process" is called `sched` in a non-zoned (or inside the "global" / admin zone) environment but [`zsched`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1460/z.inst.ov-13.html) inside a zone.
- The Solaris [`prstat`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/prstat-1m.html) command (similar to `top` on other UN*Xes) has `-z` / `-Z` command line options to restrict reporting to specific zones (`-z`) or give statistics for all zones (`-Z`); inside a zone, these options don't work / only show you the zone you're running inside.

Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

I used this way:

```
#elif defined (__sun__)

/* Similar to Linux
 * XXX: check zone?
 * XXX: illumos kernel automatically mounts /proc on boot
 */

static int ischroot()
{
  struct stat st1, st2;

  if (stat("/", &st1))
    return 2;
  if (stat("/proc/1/root", &st2))
    return 2;
  if ((st1.st_dev == st2.st_dev) && (st1.st_ino == st2.st_ino))
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

#else
```